# Probability of words

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The question is as follows:

> A word of $6$ letters is formed from a set of $16$ different letters of English alphabet (with replacement). Find out the probability that exactly two letters are repeated.

What I think is there is a word that has six letters among which there are there are two that have repetitions i.e. among the 6 only 4 are different, rest are repetitions.

Based on this, I first found out the total number of 6 letter words possible from the 16 letters. It is, of course $16^6$. Now to find out the required no. of words, I have the following expression (E is event space),
$$ n(E) = {16\choose 4} \times \frac{6!}{2! \times 2!}$$

That's because, I need to choose only 4 letters from 16 and then the arrangements of 6 letters in the word among which 2 and 2 are same, e.g., fghkgk. So the probability comes out to be,

$$ P(E)= \frac{{16\choose 4} \times \frac{6!}{2! \times 2!}}{16^6}$$
However the answer given is,
$$ P(E)=\frac {18080}{16^6}$$
which is much less than the answer I am getting. I would like others to explain to me what is wrong in the logic that I have used.

Comment: Your answer is not right. But the $18080$ is far too small.

Comment: HINT: imagine that the two numbers in a row make a "box". This means you have 4 other boxes to fill with letters.

Comment: There are quite a few interpretations of the problem. Is it one letter that there are $2$ of, or is it two letters that there are $2$ of? Are occurrences of the repeated letter(s) supposed to be adjacent?

Comment: I believe you need to multiply the $n(E)$ by $\binom{16-4 = 12}{1}$ more because you still have to choose the repeated pair of letters. And you should multiply by $\dfrac{6!}{2!}$ instead because there is only 1 pair of repeated letters.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think it meant the formal. He mentioned "i.e. among the 6 only 4 are different, rest are repetitions."

Comment: Does aabbbc count? (only a and b are repeated)

Comment: @AndréNicolas, yes 18080 is too small. But don't you think it is expected to be small, I mean how many words do you think will have repetitions of two letters.

Comment: A lot! I have given answers to two possible interpretations of the problem. Both produce a substantially larger number. But of course these numbers are smallish in comparison with the denominator $16^6$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That comparison is what I was talking about.

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible interpretations of the problem. I will assume that $2$ letters are supposed to occur twice each, and the other $2$ letters are to occur once each.

The lonely letters can be chosen in $\binom{16}{2}$ ways. For each such way, the doubled letters can be chosen in $\binom{14}{2}$ ways. Now that we have our letters, they can be arranged as you had it, in $\frac{6!}{2!2!}$ ways. Multiply. We get a big number.

If each letter that we have $2$ of is to be next to its mate, then instead of multiplying by $\frac{6!}{2!2!}$ we multiply by $4!$.

Your $\binom{16}{4}$ counts the number of ways to choose $4$ letters. However, there is a difference between having the letters a, a, b, b, c, d and having a, a, b, c, c, d.

Answer (score 1):

There are 16 different letters and we have to form words with 2 letters repeated.

Six different letters can be selected by 16C6 ways. Further, from these 6 different letters, 6! ways words can be formed.

Hence, the Exhaustive number of words = 16C6 x 6!
= 8008 x 720 words can be formed.

In the selection of 6 letters, we want exactly 2 letters (2 x 2) to be repeated. This amounts to selection of only 4 letters form the words with given condition.

Favorable cases = 16C4 x 6!/2!x 2! = 1820 x 720/4 = 1820 x 180

So, the required probability = 1820 x 180/8008 x 720 = 0.227